# Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

So basically I tried to write a function that stores user input into 3 variables and then adds them together and returns the total.

I think the problem has something to do with the `document.getElementById` part since if I for example just put in `num1 = 5;` it seems to work.

Could anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="n1"/>
    <input type="text" id="n2"/>
    <input type="text" id="n3"/>
    <button onclick="myFunction();updateGraphics();">Click Me</button>

    <p id="test"></p>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file

```
function myFunction() {

    num1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
    num2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
    num3 = document.getElementById("n3").value;

    var total = num1 + num2 + num3;

    return total;
}

var newTotal = myFunction();

function updateGraphics() {

    return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = newTotal; 

}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Your Value Here";
```

Comment: We can only tell you what is wrong if we know what is supposed to be right. Why do you think it doesn't work? Do you not get the result you expect? What is the result you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: Your number values will be strings. You'll need to coerce them to numbers, perhaps using `Number(n)`.

Comment: Write a title that summarizes a specific problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

It's because when you run `myFunction()` on the button click, its return value gets ignored. You're basically trying to use variables partially in place of a return statement.

Change your button click to have the return value of `myFunction` passed to `updateGraphics`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
  var num3 = document.getElementById("n3").value;

  return num1 + num2 + num3;
}

function updateGraphics(value) {
  return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = value;
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Your Value Here";
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1" />
<input type="text" id="n2" />
<input type="text" id="n3" />
<button onclick="updateGraphics(myFunction());">Click Me</button>

<p id="test"></p>
```

---

Of course if you don't actually need the two functions separated out, you could combine them into a single call by moving the code from one to the other.

---

As **@Teemu** pointed out, your values are going to be received as strings. You can use `parseFloat()`, `parseInt()` or the unary `+` operator on `num1`, `num2` and `num3` as possible ways to convert them to actual numbers if that's what you were expecting.

Comment: Firstly, `updateGraphics` doesn't return anything meaningful. Secondly, `myFunction` doesn't take any arguments. ??

Comment: @Teemu: Depending on the expected result, that may indeed be an issue.

Comment: @clabe45: Yeah, I just reversed the function names at first. Already updated.

Answer (score 1):

Without you posting an example of it not working, cast the values to integers (or floats). JavaScript's default when "adding" strings is to concatenate, even if it is actually a number-string.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, too, but the OP never said he/she was adding numbers.

Comment: I think the variable names speak for themselves :)

Comment: Oh the OP did mention a `5` somewhere. Oh yes the var names do !!

Answer (score 1):

```
 var newTotal = myFunction();
```

this executes myFunction *once* and sets newTotal. Whenever you call *myFunction*, it wont update newTotals value. For that, just declare it outside, then update from the inside of the function:

```
var newTotal;
function myFunction(){
  //whatever
  newTotal = 12;
}
```

All in all, you may restructure your code like this:

```
function getSum() {

  num1 = + document.getElementById("n1").value;
  num2 = + document.getElementById("n2").value;
  num3 = + document.getElementById("n3").value;

  return num1 + num2 + num3;
}

function updateGraphics(value) {
 return document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = value; 
}

updateGraphics("Your Value Here");

document.getElementByTagName("button")[0].onclick = () => updateGraphics( getSum() );
```

---

getSum can even be written much shorter:

```
function getSum(){
  return ["n1", "n2"," n3"]
    .reduce((val,id)=>val + +document.getElementById(id),0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an aside: those inputs probably don't need `ids`. You can either remove them altogether or change them to classes. Then you can pick them up with `querySelector` and `reduce` the values to get the sum - something like this:

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.n');
let sum = [...inputs].reduce((p, c) => p + Number(c.value), 0);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsg68zon/)**